# add.Class() jQuery is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.product-item').click(function(){
    $("#col").addClass('left', 5000, "linear");
    $("#col .col-md-3").removeClass('col-md-3').addClass('product-open',5000,"linear");
  });

});
```

Hello , I am using `add.Class()` and `removeClass()` jQuery functions for my website , the functions are working , however I can not regulate the timer in order to add some delay to the removal and addition process , it is done instantly and it is not nice in this way , I do not understand why the timer of `addClass()` is not working ...

Comment: this is not the right way to use `addClass`

Comment: improper use of this jquery method.. https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: `addClass` as you intend to use it is provided by jQuery UI: http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/

Answer (score 3):

Because you need to include the jQuery UI
 libary.

http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/

```
<script src=//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js></script>
<script src=//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js></script>
```